# How to show boxplot flipped with another plot without flipping it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a boxplot to be overlayed on histogram. to avoid missing with the histogram, I am forced to draw the boxplot like that:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = factor(0)))
```

[image: the plot with problimatic configuartion]

However the plot doesn't appear right unless I swap between the x and y.
[image: correct plot, but not the needed configuration]

I want to integrate a histogram with boxplot on the same coordinate, but it seems there is no way to plot a boxplot flipped without using `coord_flip()` that doesn't help here as it flip the whole plot.

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = factor(0))) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: try `ggstance::geom_boxploth`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_boxploth(aes(y = 3), width = 3, color = "blue", lwd = 2, alpha = .5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This works in the current development version of ggplot2, hopefully to be released soon.

```r
library(ggplot2) # remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.2.1.9000'

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = factor(0)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>